# Getting the Index of an Array of Associative Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, dom-events, associative-array

I have an array of "associative arrays," i.e. objects, that hold the data of various HTML elements and one other parameter like so:

```
container[0] = { picker_canvas: document.getElementById("background_picker"),
                 color_canvas: document.getElementById("background_color"),
                 hex_text: document.getElementById("background_text"),
                 mouse_down: false };

container[1] = { picker_canvas: document.getElementById("textbox_picker"),
                 color_canvas: document.getElementById("textbox_color"),
                 hex_text: document.getElementById("textbox_text"),
                 mouse_down: false };

container[2] = { picker_canvas: document.getElementById("font_picker"),
                 color_canvas: document.getElementById("font_color"),
                 hex_text: document.getElementById("font_text"),
                 mouse_down: false };
```

Each container has a reference to a color picker canvas, a color preview canvas, a textbox that displays the hexadecimal color value, and a `mouse_down` boolean. Later on I initialize a few event listeners by iterating through the containers like this:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {

    container[i].picker_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
        container[i].mouse_down = true;
    }, false);

    container[i].picker_canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        container[i].mouse_down = false;
    }, false);

    container[i].picker_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
        getColor(container[i], evt);
    }, false);

    container[i].hex_text.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        drawColorSquare(container[i], evt.target.value)
    }, false);

}
```

but that doesn't work because `i` becomes undefined, so I am now trying to get the correct index by doing something like this, but I am not sure how to actually implement it in Javascript

```
container[i].picker_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
    container[container.indexof(evt.target)].mouse_down = false;
}, false);
```

basically I need to search the array of associative arrays for the `evt.target` and have it return the index of the array. So is this even possible with any built in Javascript functions or will I just have to make my own?

Comment: Just so you know, Javscript doesn't support associative arrays, it handles them as objects, so your terminology is incorrect.

Comment: Alex is right; those aren't "associative arrays." You've actually got an array of objects. "picker_canvas" and such are properties of those objects.

Comment: Also, there may be a better solution than what I answered with - can we see your HTML structure, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it seems you don't have to worry about Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, use `forEach`:

```
container.forEach(function(x) {
    x.picker_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
        x.mouse_down = true;
    }, false);

    x.picker_canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        x.mouse_down = false;
    }, false);

    x.picker_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
        getColor(x, evt);
    }, false);

    x.hex_text.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        drawColorSquare(x, evt.target.value)
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Moot point with `.addEventListener` :P Your comment just sounds wrong "In case you don't have to worry about ie8" when there's `.addEventListener`s all over the place :D

Comment: @Esailija: I wouldn't recommend it yet. On the IE side, it's not available until version 9.

Comment: I suppose we're forgetting that his script is dealing with Canvases too... go ahead with .forEach then I'd say!

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have to support IE8 here, we can go all out:

```
container.forEach(function(x) {
    x.handleEvent = function(e) { //This is stupid, wish I had the time to refactor the code to use prototypes
        switch (e.type) {
        case "mousedown":
            this.mouse_down = true;
            break;
        case "mouseup":
            this.mouse_down = false;
            break;
        case "mousemove":
            getColor(this, e);
            break;
        case "change":
            drawColorSquare(this, e.currentTarget.value);
            break;
        }
    };
    var canvas = x.picker_canvas;
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", x, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", x, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", x, false);
    x.hex_text.addEventListener("change", x, false);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass `x.handleEvent` there instead? Also, why two loops...?

Comment: @minitech see the comment. [`x.handleEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) is magical, I meant to pass the object there indeed. Otherwise `this` wouldn't work like the way I am using it.

Comment: @minitech ok you win, but it's ugly. Basically the function can be completely separated from the second loop (I.E. it can be statically defined somewhere, such as prototype) and I tried to show that :D

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Prototypes would be neatest, so if you don't have the time, I'd be more than happy ;)

Comment: @minitech I actually have time but it just feels like it would be a lot of work. And this answer isn't picking up the upvotes like I hoped it would :D